# Array programming/vectorization: faster code?

Tags: arrays, vector, octave, vectorization

Lately, I've been enjoying [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) in Octave: treating vectors/matrices as scalars and don't worry about the underlying looping etc to calculate matrix multiplication and so on.

Someone told me that, next to being less prone to errors, it is also faster because the compiler/interpreter can optimize calculations under the hood.

I don't know why this would be the case. Could anyone shed a light on why vectorization/array programming would be more efficient? It is because calculations can be done in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the processor has instructions that can operate on multiple pieces of data simultaneously. You can only take advantage of these if you batch up similar work and do it all at the same time.

There are several performance gains:

- The processor has multiple execution units, which might otherwise be idle during scalar operations.
- The data is accessed at the same time, meaning it will likely be in a similar place in memory and in the various levels of CPU caches.
- It requires fewer processor instructions to complete the same amount of work, freeing up resources in the front-end of the processor pipeline as it has less work to do.

To take advantage of these instructions without using them directly, you'll need to arrange your code in a compiler friendly way. And in your case that means taking advantage of matrix and vector objects.

Answer (score 4):

A big reason that cause loops to be slow in Octave is that is runs in an interpreter unlike languages such as Java or C which are usually compiled. [This article](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/general-miscellaneous/whats-the-difference-between-a-compiled-and-an-interpreted-language/) explains the difference between and interpreter and a compiler but basically a compiler translates your code into low level code your CPU can run (probably via the OS) before your programme runs. These languages are often strongly typed, i.e. you have to declare all your variables upfront, and so they can look ahead at all the code and optimize how the programme will allocate memory and order it's calculations etc. On the other hand, an interpreter translates your code line by line on the fly at run time. This means it has no idea what memory or calculations will occur in the future. There is also the overhead of interpreting while running.

So why do matrix operations run faster in Octave, an interpreted language? This is because many of the built-in functions are actually pre-compiled in another Language (in MATLAB it's C, not sure for Octave but I would guess the same) and so they enjoy the speed up advantages of compiled code.

Further to that, you can probably fairly assume that they are using better algorithms than you are. Consider for example matrix multiplication. The naive way to code this is a triple nested for loop that runs in O(n^3). However there are [more complex algorithms](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Matrix_multiplication#/Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication) that can provide sub-cubic run-times and that can lead to huge speed-ups. Lastly, I know in MATLAB and so I assume in Octave as well, that many common built-in functions are also compiled to take advantage of multicore processes via parellelization.

Comment: In Octave it depends which Operation you are talking about. The core is implemented in C++, for example elementwise Matrix Multiplikation. The normal Matrix Multiplikation is done through the used BLAS lib (for example ATLAS which does many optimizations for specific CPU types) and a huge bunch of Fortran Code